# Transform string with term enclosed in quotes and separated by commas into array of subarrays in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a Mysql database with one field that contains a string of terms in quotes separated by commas, I need to turn that field into an array or arrays and add to each term some information that will be updated in the future, as the example below.

field value: "Individuals, groups and populations","Diversity and inclusion","Protection"

Result it an array or arrays such:

"Partof": [
{
"term": "Individuals, groups and populations",
"definition": ""
},
{
"term": "Diversity and inclusion",
"definition": ""
},
{
"term": "Protection",
"definition": ""
}
],

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_split to get the items in array.

```
<?php
$str = '"Individuals, groups and populations","Diversity and inclusion","Protection"';
$pattern = '/\"*\"/';
$components = preg_split($pattern, $str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$components = array_diff($components,array(','));
print_r($components);

$a = array();
foreach($components as $c){
$array = null;
$array['term'] = $c;
$array['definition'] = "";
array_push($a,json_encode($array));
}
print_r($a);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Mann, brilliant, this is the way I needed it, I was playing with preg_split but didn't get the right pattern. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try use [json-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to converts it into a PHP variable.